# Can I use < and > in my meta title and is it allowed by Google?

Tags: google, html, search-engine-indexing, search-results

I want to use in title  `Get <my special product> at offer price`.

Is it allowed by Google and HTML standard to use `< and >` in meta title?

Comment: That title is rather weak. Yes you're using a product name, but you don't have anything describing it. you're emphasizing on a fixed price that people don't search for in search engines. Now if you insist on using `<` and `>`, then you'll have to use proper HTML codes. These may work: `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>` respectively.